# Convert First Character Of Every Word In A String To Upper Case

Tags: jquery, html

Is There Any jQuery Plugin Which Allows Me to Convert

```
var data="steve, computer application , stanford university"
```

into

```
Steve, Computer Application , Stanford University
```

sorry for this lame question am new to jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the following code

```
    var data="steve, computer application , stanford university"

data = data.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
});
alert(data);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/97kuarLs/)